# junit test cases using mockito for query output

Tags: java, junit, mockito

this is my code sample below for which i am trying to mock a unit test case:

```
      public create Test(){
        ResponseEntity<Create> result = restTemplate.exchange(.....,Create.class);
        if(result.getStatusCode !=null){
        return result.getBody.id;
        }
      else {
        throw new Runtime Exception();
       }
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Create{
        public String id;
        public String[] errors;
        public boolean success;
    }
```

The mockito test case i am writing throws me a null poniter exception at the if statement. This is what i have tried so far:

```
Create create = new Create();
        create = "id";
create.errors = "errors";
        create.success = "success" != null;
Mockito.when(exchange.getStatusCode()..equals(HttpStatus.CREATED)).thenReturn(null);
```

I have successfully mocked my result and rest template exchange and it fails particularly in this if statement line.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly at the if statement?

Comment: If you are refereing to if(result.getStatusCode !=null), it seems this statement is returning null: restTemplate.exchange(.....,Create.class)

Comment: I am refering to if(result.getStatuscode != null){}, the whole block

Comment: Can you double check that this is not returning null: restTemplate.exchange(.....,Create.class).

Answer (score 0):

You're attributing "id" to your "create" object and you're using double dots after `getStatusCode()`. The correct should be:

```
        create.id = "id";
create.errors = "errors";
        create.success = "success" != null;
Mockito.when(exchange.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.CREATED)).thenReturn(null);
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, my original code does not have it, and it still fails